# Error when vectorizing mapping with tf.data.Dataset()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.x

I have an image dataset that I retrieved by means of `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()`.

In my `.map()` function, I read and decode images, like below:

```
def map_function(filepath):
    image = tf.io.read_file(filename=filepath)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT])
    return image
```

If I use(this below works)

```
 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=...)
 dataset = dataset.map(map_function)
 for image in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    #Correctly outputs the numpy array, no error is displayed/encountered
    print(image)
```

However, if I use(this below throws error):

```
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=...)
  dataset = dataset.batch(32).map(map_function)
  for image in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    #Error is displayed 
      print(image)
```

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op:
>   'ReadFile') with input shapes: [?].

Now, according to this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#vectorizing_mapping, the code should not fail and the preprocessing step should be optimized(batch processing vs one-time-processing).

Where is the mistake in my code?

*** If I use `map().batch()` it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because `map_function` expects unbatched elements, but in the second example you give it batched elements.

The example in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance is being tricky by defining an `increment` function which can apply to both batched and unbatched elements, since adding 1 to a batched element like [1, 2, 3] will result in [2, 3, 4].

```py
def increment(x):
    return x+1
```

To use vectorization, you would need to write a `vectorized_map_function`, which takes in a vector of unbatched elements, applies the map function to each element in the vector, then returns a vector of the results.

In your case though, I don't think vectorizing will have a noticeable impact, since the cost of reading and decoding files is much higher than the overhead of calling a function. Vectorization is most impactful when the map function is extremely cheap, to the point where the time spent on function invocation is comparable to the time spent doing actual work in the map function.